# How to grab info from HTML page?

Tags: html, powershell

Please, help me grab information from this structure:

```html
<table id="id1" class="class1">
<tbody>
    <tr id="id2">
        <td>
            <span class="class2">
            <a href="/folder1/folder2/id412217">"header text"</a>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td id="d" style="width:10px;">
            <img style="width:10px;" src="/images/img1.gif">
        </td>
        <td id="r" style="width:40%;">
            <span class="class2">
                <nobr>Headings:</nobr>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="class1" style="width:100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="300" valign="top"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px;">
                            <div>
                                <b>Address: </b>
                                <a href="/folder1/folder2/id412217">Address text</a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <b>Tel.: </b>
                                250-1729
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="/images/img.gif">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/yp/folder2/rubric1067/">heading1</a>
            <br>
            <a href="/yp/folder2/rubric1068/">heading2</a>
            <br>
            <a href="/yp/folder2/rubric1063/">heading3</a>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get:

- header text
- Address text
- Tel. number

but I don't understand, how can I get it with PowerShell.

Firstly, I get this table

```
$address = "http://address.com"
$page  = Invoke-WebRequest $address
$table = $($page.parsedhtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Where { $_.id -eq 'id1' })
```

What's next?
How can I call table's children and get their texts?

Comment: See also: [PowerShell: Extracting HTML table as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67162906/1701026)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my decision:

```
$address = "http://address.com"
$page  = Invoke-WebRequest $address
$table = $($page.parsedhtml.getElementById("id1")
$tr = $table.getElementsByTagName('tr') | Where { $_.id -eq 'id2' }
$name=($tr.getElementsByTagName('a') | select -First 1).innertext
$divs=$table.getElementsByTagName('div')
    foreach ($div in $divs) {
        if ($div.innertext -match "address: ") {$adr=$div.innertext -replace "Address: ",""}
        if ($div.innertext -match "Tel.: ") {$tel=$div.innertext -replace "Tel.: ",""}
    }
$resultmassive+=[string]::Join(";",$name,$adr,$tel)
```

p.s. Maybe, it is possible to use PowerShell switch-case construcion instead foreach, but it doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: if your elements have an ID use `getElementById()` instead of `getElementsByTagName()` with an additional filter. That will give you the correct table (or other element) right away.

When you have the (parent) element you can get nested elements by calling `getElementById()`, `getElementsByTagName()`, etc. on the parent:

```
$nestedTables = $table.getElementsByTagName('table')
```

In your case you want to get

- the child element with the ID `id2` and then the (grand)child `<a>` element (for the header text)

  ```
  $tr = $table.getElementById('id2')
  $tr.getElementsByTagName('a')
  ```
- the `<div>` elements in the nested table (for the address and phone number):

  ```
  $table.getElementsByTagName('div')
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

 I can't get nested element by id. Variable with table has no methods for this, it has GetElementsByClassName, GetElementsByTagName, GetElementsByTagNameNS. There is no "GetElementById".

So, i'm getting my "tr" tag by his tagname with a filter by "id"
 `$tr = $table.getElementsByTagName('tr') | Where { $_.id -eq 'id2' }`

Then, i'm getting his nested tag "a"
 `$ta=$tr.getElementsByTagName('a')`

But, it has no parameters like "innerText" etc.