# HTML Table to CSV File in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi can anyone explain this:

```
$Table = $HTML -split '\<\/table\>' -replace '\<[^\?t]+[^\<]*','' -replace ' \w+="\w+%?"','' -replace '\<t\w+\>',',' -replace ',,\s?|,\r\n','' -replace ',\s',',' -replace ':,',': ' -replace "%","`r`n" -replace "\r\n,","`r`n"
# $Table | Out-File -FilePath "File.csv"
```

Comment: The answer from [@broffutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17801412/broffutt) gives some explanation about what the concerned syntax does but in general, I recommend against [attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  
Instead use a dedicated HTML parser as the [**HtmlDocument** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), see also: [Extracting HTML table as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67161977/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

That code goes through and uses regex to replace certain characters with a comma to create comma separated values, or CSV.

It then uses `Out-File` to push the CSV data to a CSV file. [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2) literally just sends the data to a file.

If you are curious what the regex means, you can go to [this site](https://regex101.com/) and paste each regex expression. The right hand side of the site will explain in detail what it is doing.